# "Error while downloading 'http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd' "

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm new to java and learning JSP tag libraries. while creating ".tld" file I got this error, I just don't know what's gone wrong.

here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">
    
    <taglib> //this tag got the problem
        <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
        <jsp-version>1.0</jsp-version>
        <short-name>st</short-name>
        
        <tag>
        <name></name>
        
        </tag>
    </taglib>
```

full Error message

```
Error while downloading 'http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd' to C:\Users\Dell\.lemminx\cache\http\java.sun.com\j2ee\dtd\web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd.
```

please help me get this right if you know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<taglib> 
//put empty line 
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <jsp-version>1.0</jsp-version>
    <short-name>st</short-name>
    <uri></uri>
    
    <tag>
    <name>MyDate</name>
    <tag-class>com.isuru.PrintDateTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
    
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).